Github Packages: Prevent users from being able to publish packages from their own machine?
Devs on my team have been publishing their locally-made builds to github. I want to prevent them from being able to do this. I did a bit of research, and got to thinking perhaps I need to prevent them from having the packages:write scope, shown here:

But I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Note that I do want folks to be able to run Github actions, some of which create builds and publish packages. But I don't want them to be able to publish packages outside of running an Action.
I've taken a look here, at Github Packages permissions: https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages. The repo in question is an Angular library, and I want to prevent folks from publishing to Github's npm.
Note also that these people do need write permission for the repository in terms of making code changes and such, it's just they don't need to be publishing packages.
